# A problem with transitivity of ordering of stationary sets

Tags: set-theory

In chapter 8 of Jech's Set Theory in the Third Millenium, he defines the following ordering on stationary sets: $S<T$ if the set $\{\alpha\in T:\alpha\cap S\text{ is stationary}\}$ is stationary. He goes on to state that

1. $S<\text{Tr}(S)$,
2. $S<T$ and $T<Q$ implies that $S<Q$, and
3. that if $S\sim S',T\sim T'$ modulo $I_{NS}$ and $S<T$, then $S'<T'$.

The first seems to be obvious, but I'm having trouble seeing why (2) and (3) are true.

Comment: At least in my version he defines $S < T$ iff $\{ \alpha \in T \mid S \cap \alpha \text{ is non-stationary} \}$ is non-stationary (which is not equivalent to the definition that you provided here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you’ve misinterpreted **Definition** $\mathbf{8.18}$. I’ll quote it and the sentence that precedes it.

> In the context of closed unbounded and stationary sets we use the phrase *for almost all* $\alpha\in S$ to mean that the set of all contrary $\alpha\in S$ is nonstationary.
>
> **Definition** $\mathbf{8.18.}$ Let $S$ and $T$ be stationary subsets of $\kappa$.
>
> $$S<T\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad S\cap\alpha\text{ is stationary for almost all }\alpha\in T\;.$$

The given set of $\alpha\in T$ is $\{\alpha\in T:S\cap\alpha\text{ is stationary}\}$. To say that almost all $\alpha\in T$ are in this set is to say that set of $\alpha\in T$ that are **not** in this set — i.e., the set of **contrary** $\alpha\in T$ — is nonstationary. In other words, $S<T$ iff $S\cap\alpha$ is stationary for almost all $\alpha\in T$ iff the set $\{\alpha\in T:S\cap\alpha\text{ is not stationary}\}$ is nonstationary.

Think of non-stationary sets as *small*, their complements as *large*, and stationary sets as *not small (but not necessarily large)*. When we say that $\varphi(\alpha)$ holds for almost all $\alpha\in S$, we mean that the set of $\alpha\in S$ for which $\varphi(\alpha)$ fails is small (is non-stationary); this is stronger than saying that the set of $\alpha\in S$ for which $\varphi(\alpha)$ holds is not small (is stationary).

Comment: I think I see the problem now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jgaebler: You’re welcome!